# SSH file transfer between Pi 2 Model B and Windows 10 computer

Tags: python, pi-2

I use a piece of software called FileZilla to transfer any files to and from Pi and my Windows 10 computer. Is there any way to eliminate the use of this software? Like a Pi terminal command? Or Python code?

Comment: You can use all kind of software which is using `sftp` communication protocol. So you can write your own python script to transfer data.

Comment: try to Google "Windows mount ssh disk"

Answer (score 1):

You could set up samba on the Pi and share a folder. Make sure you give that folder read and write permissions.

install samba: `sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin`

For more info try [this documentation](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html).